# Setting a random seed on TF 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have just upgraded from TF 1.13 to TF 2.0, and my interpreter is complaining because `tf.set_random_seed` does no longer exist.

What is the equivalent functionality in TF 2.0 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it: `tf.random.set_seed` is what I was looking for